# How that I read properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, properties

I made a web service with Java and SpringBoot, but when I compile and run the .jar file, the Java search for the properties file and don't find it by the path I'm using, I tried to use the inverted bar too, but not worked.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.5)

2021-09-29 08:54:10.031  INFO 7956 --- [           main] b.c.l.d.price.DollarPriceApplication     : Starting DollarPriceApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.2 on DESKTOP-7MASP9B with PID 7956 (D:\git\DollarPrice\DollarPricing\target\DollarPrice.jar started by leohm in D:\git\DollarPrice\DollarPricing\target)
2021-09-29 08:54:10.035  INFO 7956 --- [           main] b.c.l.d.price.DollarPriceApplication     : The following profiles are active: dev
2021-09-29 08:54:11.872  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-09-29 08:54:11.875  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-29 08:54:11.930  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface br.com.leomanzini.dollar.price.repository.HistoryDollarRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-09-29 08:54:11.933  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface br.com.leomanzini.dollar.price.repository.RealTimeDollarRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-09-29 08:54:11.934  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 52 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2021-09-29 08:54:11.953  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-09-29 08:54:11.956  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-29 08:54:12.030  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 57 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-29 08:54:14.382  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-29 08:54:14.400  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-29 08:54:14.400  INFO 7956 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2021-09-29 08:54:14.484  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-29 08:54:14.485  INFO 7956 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4316 ms
2021-09-29 08:54:14.922  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-09-29 08:54:15.049  INFO 7956 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-09-29 08:54:15.555  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-09-29 08:54:15.913  INFO 7956 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-09-29 08:54:16.294  INFO 7956 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-09-29 08:54:16.383  INFO 7956 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists history cascade
2021-09-29 08:54:18.525  WARN 7956 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-09-29 08:54:18.526  WARN 7956 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "history" does not exist, skipping
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists realtime cascade
2021-09-29 08:54:18.532  WARN 7956 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-09-29 08:54:18.533  WARN 7956 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : table "realtime" does not exist, skipping
Hibernate:

    create table history (
       quote_id int8 generated by default as identity,
        price varchar(255),
        date_time varchar(255),
        variation varchar(255),
        primary key (quote_id)
    )
Hibernate:

    create table realtime (
       quote_id int8 generated by default as identity,
        code varchar(255),
        codein varchar(255),
        price varchar(255),
        date_time varchar(255),
        primary key (quote_id)
    )
2021-09-29 08:54:18.782  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-09-29 08:54:18.820  INFO 7956 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-29 08:54:19.751  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :

Using generated security password: ebf29ab7-b395-43fa-9508-6b6513d5360e

2021-09-29 08:54:20.055  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@36327cec, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4730e0f0, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1f1e58ca, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@410ae5ac, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@24534cb0, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@77c233af, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5399f6c5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1a8df0b3, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2f521c4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6b6b3572, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@14998e21]
2021-09-29 08:54:21.678  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-09-29 08:54:21.693  INFO 7956 --- [           main] b.c.l.d.price.DollarPriceApplication     : Started DollarPriceApplication in 12.495 seconds (JVM running for 13.703)
2021-09-29 08:54:35.824  INFO 7956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-09-29 08:54:35.826  INFO 7956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-09-29 08:54:35.830  INFO 7956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
2021-09-29 08:54:35.987 ERROR 7956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] b.c.l.d.price.utils.PropertiesLoader     : src\main\resources\application.properties (O sistema n▒o pode encontrar o caminho especificado)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: BOOT-INF\classes\application.properties (O sistema n▒o pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112) ~[na:na]
        at br.com.leomanzini.dollar.price.utils.PropertiesLoader.load(PropertiesLoader.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at br.com.leomanzini.dollar.price.service.DollarPriceService.loadProperties(DollarPriceService.java:87) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at br.com.leomanzini.dollar.price.service.DollarPriceService.getRealTimeDollarPrice(DollarPriceService.java:42) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at br.com.leomanzini.dollar.price.controller.DollarPriceController.getRealTimeDollarPrice(DollarPriceController.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar!/:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-09-29 08:54:44.547  INFO 7956 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-29 08:54:44.548  INFO 7956 --- [ionShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists history cascade
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists realtime cascade
2021-09-29 08:54:44.653  INFO 7956 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-09-29 08:54:44.703  INFO 7956 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

There is a way to use another path or which is the correct way to use it correctly that Java find the file?

The code hierarchy and the properties path below.

[image: hierachy]

The properties loader class that I'm using

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public abstract class PropertiesLoader {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(PropertiesLoader.class);

    private static final String PROPERTIES_REAL_TIME_URL = "real.time.dollar.price";
    private static final String PROPERTIES_HISTORY_URL = "history.dollar.price";
    private static final String PROPERTIES_PATH = "BOOT-INF\\classes\\application.properties";

    private static String realTimeUrl;
    private static String historyUrl;

    private PropertiesLoader() {
    }

    public static void load() {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream(PROPERTIES_PATH));

            realTimeUrl = props.getProperty(PROPERTIES_REAL_TIME_URL);
            historyUrl = props.getProperty(PROPERTIES_HISTORY_URL);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    public static String getRealTimeUrl() {
        return realTimeUrl;
    }
    
    public static String getHistoryUrl() {
        return historyUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of PropertiesLoader

Comment: Sorry, code pasted.

Comment: WHy? Spring boot already loads that file why load it again yourself to expose properties. Ditch your `PropertiesLoader` and just use `@Value` or the `Environment` to get the properties.

Answer (score 2):

You did not paste the code you use to read the file, but reading 'I used an inverted bar too' as: "You were using a backslash", that rather strongly hints you are using `java.nio.file.Path`, `java.io.File`, or `java.io.FileInputStream` to attempt to read this thing.

None of those work. As the name suggests, those work on *files*, and your `application.properties` item is not a file; not at runtime, anyway: It is an entry in a jar. Not a file.

To read these, you use this mechanism:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream in = Example.class.getResource("/application-prod.properties")) {
          // use in here
        }
    }
}
```

This will tell java to find the place where `Example.class` was loaded from (even if that is in a jar), then go to the 'root' of that source (that is what the leading slash is for), and then look for that entry. Even in a jar. Even if loaded over a network.

However, the usual idea with properties files is **not** to do it this way; instead, you want the properties file to be in the user's home dir - the point is that they are easily editable, and 'open the jar file, edit this properties file inside it' is not exactly 'easily editable'.

One somewhat common pattern is to store the *default* properties file in the jar (e.g. in the `src/main/resources` folder, whose entries end up in your jar), and then if the properties file is not in the place you are looking for it, such as the user's home dir or some application dir, to copy the template over and inform the user that they can now edit it.

Comment: And I have to use this passing a path to the properties or not?

Comment: No, you can't pass a path to properties, as this entity isn't a path. You pass the inputstream.